# Working and Studying in Russia

Tags: russia, study, work, nigerian-citizens

I have a question i want to ask at this time. If i have a study permit visa for Russia can  I work and study same time in Russia, like work part time and study full time for the number of credit hours allotted? I speak English as a Nigerian, would I have opportunity of working as someone from an English speaking Nation?

Comment: Assuming you get permission to work, your chances of finding a job depend on your skills and what you want to do. Could you edit the question to be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you’re employed at a university, you need a permit to work. https://studyinrussia.ru/en/life-in-russia/arriving-in-russia/job-for-students/ The permit will state what type of work you’re allowed to do and where.